# Are modular form theory applicable to representation of sum of higher powers

Tags: soft-question, modular-forms

just a disclaimer before my question, I don't *really* know too much about modular forms, as I just started learning it. However, any answers whether technical or not are very welcomed!

I know that modular forms are useful in quadratic form theory. Some examples I know of are counting the number of representations of an integer as sum of four integers ($s_4(n)$), and Tunnell's theorem on congruent numbers. My main question is whether the theory is applicable to higher powers or not, e.g. counting $S(n) = \left\{a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + d^4 : (a, b, c, d) \in \mathbb{Z}^4\right\}$. I suppose that if it can be, then one would form the generating function $\Theta_4(q) := \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{k^4}$ and analyse that. However, the proof of $\Theta_2^4$ satisfying the transformation formula for modular forms, which AFAIK among many other things, uses the fact that $f(x) = e^{-\pi x^2}$ is the fourier transform of itself, and I don't think any analogous results hold for $\Theta_4$. Hence, I suppose that the theory can't be directly applied this way, but I guess my real question is:

Are there any other possible approaches to still use modular forms or generalisations of it to attack this problem, or is it really limited to quadratic forms? Are there any "intuitive" reasons to why that is?

(Other analytic NT methods like circle method is irrelevant here.)

Comment: See, e.g., Waibel, F. Fourier coefficients of half-integral weight cusp forms and Waring’s problem. Ramanujan J 47, 185–200 (2018). https://doi.org/10.1007/s11139-017-9934-1; Abstract: Extending the approach of Iwaniec and Duke, we present strong uniform bounds for Fourier coefficients of half-integral weight cusp forms of level N. As an application, we consider a Waring-type problem with sums of mixed powers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, I have have a look when I learn more about modular forms, it seems quite scary at the moment.

Comment: Here's something relevant. When considering the sum of $k$ squares special case of Waring's problem. It was proven by Hardy and Ramanujan that the main term obtained from the circle method is exact for $k\le8$. This is achieved by investigating the modularity of the generating function formed by the main term, which involves summing the singular series arithmetically. Perhaps a similar procedure can be done on the general Waring problem.

Comment: @TravorLZH Are you referring to the paper "On the representation of a number as the sum of any number of squares, and in particular of five" by Hardy? Or do you mind providing any reference :)

Comment: Another one would be Ramanujan: Twelve lectures on subjects suggested by his life and work